# Getting out of memory exception when picking images Camera/Gallery

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-camera

I am picking Images through Camera/Gallery using the below code and save their paths in Sq Lite that's fine. Everything is working.

My problem is after pick image 40 or above, I am getting an out of memory exception.

Can some one help please?

## chooseImageFromCamera:

```
try {
    String folder_main = "FOSImages";
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.mkdirs();
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File f1 = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "/" + folder_main + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "_temp.jpg");
    fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + "_temp.jpg";
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f1));
    startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
} catch (Throwable throwable) {
    throwable.printStackTrace();
}
```

### onCaptureImageResult:

```
try {
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "FOSImages");
    for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
        if (temp.getName().equals(fileName)) {
            f = temp;
            origionalPaths.add(f);
            if (imageType == 1) {
                stickerBeforeFileList.add(f);
                horizentalAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                stickerAfterFileList.add(f);
                horizentalAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

} catch (Throwable throwable) {
    throwable.printStackTrace();
}
```

### chooseFromLibrary:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
            Constants.GALLARY_REQUEST_CODE);

} catch (Throwable throwable) {
    throwable.printStackTrace();
}
```

### onSelectFromGalleryResult:

```
try {
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    File shopImageFile1 = new 
 File(Utilities.getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri, UberFormActivity.this));
    if (imageType == 1) {
        stickerBeforeFileList.add(carImageFile1);
        horizentalAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        stickerAfterFileList.add(carImageFile2);
        horizentalAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
} catch (Throwable throwable) {
    throwable.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: you can try and compress your image before loading it. Check this link : https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

Comment: https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor using this i already compress the image

Comment: but still i am getting same exception above link working good for compressing

Comment: **Set a limit** to choose images. It is good practice because you might be able to pick 40 images on one device. there might be some other devices with low spec where it may give you same `outofmemoryerror` on picking 40 images as well. So better to set a limit of image like ~20 or 30.

Comment: I think this is not solve my issue because in another case i try after pick the each image i send that to server and delete form my device then same problem i am facing after 40 images above

Comment: but there's no sqlite related code.

Comment: i think there is no problem in sql related code thats why not posted